# How Delete A Windows 7 dll File (In System32 Folder) By C# Language

Tags: c#, file, .net-4.0, delete-file, permission-denied

Sometimes I need to delete or replace a dll file in system32 folder of windows 7.
The code below always has `Permission Denied Error` :

```
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\system32\mydll.dll"))
            {
                fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                File.Delete(@"C:\Windows\system32\mydll.dll");
            }
```

How can I bypass this error and replace a file in system32 folder?

Comment: You either need administrator privileges, right click the program and select "Run as Administrator"/edit the app manifest to prompt for it, or your account does not have permission to make change to the system folder. If the DLL is loaded into memory I don't know if you can delete it.

Comment: @0_______0 thanks for the comment.  but i am administrator... problem is still there.

Comment: By default I don't think you can delete/edit any system files without changing the permissions. Programmer's answer will take ownership of it and grant the permission to delete it.

Comment: What happens if you try deleting the file manually, or through command prompt? Wondering if Windows give you the same problem. I also wonder why you've trying to do this. If it's a 'system' file, I'd highly advise deleting on a reboot task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user doesn't have sufficient rights to delete files from c:\windows\system32 on Windows Vista and up.  Even when logged-on using an administrator account.  UAC puts a stop to it.  You *must* ask for elevation to let the user know that you are about to tinker with the private parts.  That requires embedding a manifest in your program to trigger the UAC prompt.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-c-sharp-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7/2818776#2818776) shows you how.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\mydll.dll"))
{
    new Process() { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/k takeown /f C:\Windows\System32\mydll.dll && icacls C:\Windows\System32\mydll.dll /grant %username%:F") }.Start();
    File.Delete(@"C:\Windows\System32\mydll.dll");
}
```

Note that you can't delete a system DLL like `shell32.dll` even after taking ownership but you can rename or move it.

Comment: thanks for the edit and comment. but i don't know why i always have an exception (can not find file) by your example? (we should put a @ sign befire "CMD..., am i right?)